# Can we control number of documents to return in RetrievalQA Langchain

Tags: openai-api, langchain, large-language-model, nlp-question-answering, llama

Can we control the document query parameter in RetrievalQA() like we could do in vectorDBQA() in langchain before? Also, shall I use map_reduce chain type instead for my large documents?

I tried to look into the source code but could not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customized the Retrieval and add your requirement

```
   class URRetrival(BaseRetriever):

    def __int__(self):
        pass

    def setparms(self, count):
        self.count = count


    def _get_relevant_documents(
            self, query: str, *, run_manager: CallbackManagerForRetrieverRun
    ) -> List[Document]:
        
        # need to add your similarity search here and add set self.count as limit
    #results = your vectordb.similarity(limit_or_k = self.count)
        return results

    async def _aget_relevant_documents(
            self,
            query: str,
            *,
            run_manager: AsyncCallbackManagerForRetrieverRun,
            **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> List[Document]:
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

in above example you need to add your vector db , its depend on you which you are using, and return the similarity results, the vector db supported for k/limit of relative docs

_get_relevant_documents : method call when inside the chain, you need to pass this costume retrieval as chain retrieval

Example:

```
retrival = URRetrival()
retrival.setparms(5)
qa_with_sources_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm,
    retriever=retrival,
    callbacks=[handler],
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it as below:

```
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA

qa_with_sources = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm, chain_type="stuff", retriever=docsearch.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': #_of_docs_to_return}),return_source_documents=True)
```